# MySQL syntax error on adding foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that look like the following:

http://pastebin.com/AwRJJiPE

I am then trying to add a foreign key constraint like so:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `Order`
    -> ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_baseline_order`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY `baselineId`
    ->     REFERENCES `Baseline` (`id`)
    ->     ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I get the following "syntax" error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'REFERENCES `Baseline` (`id`)
>       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE' at line 4

I for the life of me can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: Deleted my answer, I misread the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the referencing columns between parenthesis as well:

```
ALTER TABLE `Order`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_baseline_order`
      FOREIGN KEY (`baselineId`)     <<<<-- here
      REFERENCES `Baseline` (`id`)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your foriegn key column inside parenthesis like

```
ALTER TABLE `Order`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_baseline_order`
     FOREIGN KEY (`baselineId`) <-- Here
    REFERENCES `Baseline` (`id`)
     ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```